# SVG animation struggles with Safari 13.1 (Mac OS & IOS)

Tags: css, svg, safari, css-animations, svg-animate

I just realized that the latest version of Safari (v13.1) that comes with macOs 10.15.4 and iOS 13.4 doesn't support css animations in SVG files anymore.
I use this trick to display a loading animation on my portfolio. Now only the first frame of the sag file is display and the animation doesn't start.
https://jbkaloya.com

[image: Safari 13.1]

No issues with Chrome or Firefox tho.

[image: Chrome (working)]

**EDIT**

Here's the corresponding CSS properties in where the file is embedded in the page

```css
.loading {
  background-color: $black-color;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1100;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .4s 0s cubic-bezier(.455,.03,.515,.955), z-index 0s 0s linear;
  
  &::before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(../images/logoanimated.svg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 max-width: 22rem;
 margin: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
  }
```

I guess it can also be related to those properties (that are located in the svg file and that start the animation sequence)

```css
    {
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-iteration-count: 1
      }
```

Am I the only one concern by this issue ?

Safari 13.1 changelog: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_13_1_beta_release_notes

Comment: report a webkit bug to the webkit bugtracker with your testcase.

Comment: What are you talking about ?
SMIL has not been supported for years !

Comment: @MisterJojo SMIL is supported in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. This question is however about CSS animation and not SMIL.

Comment: you are supposed to produce a minimal code illustrating your problem not an entire site with hundreds of lines of code to peel to understand what you are talking about

Comment: @ MisterJojo That's true, thanks for your feedback. I've edited my post to make it more understandable

Comment: @RobertLongson Strangely this bug only occurs on the latest version of Safari(13.1) and not the rest of the webkit browsers.

Comment: Regardless you still [report it here](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)

Comment: Did you end up reporting this? I can't seem to find it on their bugzilla, and I'd like to reference it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar issue. To resolve, I utilized an object with type set to image/svg+xml.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="animation/some.svg">
```

Comment: A huge thanks ! That worked perfectly. Do you know the technical reason ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteKaloya I don't know what the specifics are, but there's some things that SVG images _aren't_ allowed to do when embedded with the `<img>` tag. The one that I know about for sure is that they're not allowed to load things from external resources, e.g. webfonts. I'd say someone was working in this code on webkit and accidentally introduced a regression.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue with some svg animations not working in Safari

The solution ended up being to move all the `<clipPath>` nodes to the top of the `<def>` node, before the `<animate>` nodes that reference the clipPaths in their `xlink:href`

i.e. change this:

```
<def>
  <animate repeatCount="indefinite" dur="5.76s" begin="0s" xlink:href="#_R_G_L_1_C_0_P_0" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" from="..." keyTimes="..." keySplines="..." calcMode="spline"/>
  <clipPath id="_R_G_L_1_C_0">
    <path id="_R_G_L_1_C_0_P_0" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
  </clipPath>
  ...
</def>
```

to this:

```
<def>
  <clipPath id="_R_G_L_1_C_0">
    <path id="_R_G_L_1_C_0_P_0" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
  </clipPath>
  <animate repeatCount="indefinite" dur="5.76s" begin="0s" xlink:href="#_R_G_L_1_C_0_P_0" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" from="..." keyTimes="..." keySplines="..." calcMode="spline"/>
  ...
</def>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue on Safari and iOS. I solved it by using an `<img>` tag instead of in-lining the `<svg>` and applying a CSS animation to it.